# Can I work around the iText7 "Error at File Pointer" exception?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I'm trying to read text from a specific PDF file (https://www.mass.gov/files/documents/2019/07/15/jud-lib-310cmr7.pdf), and I'm getting this exception from iText7:

```
Error at file pointer 1358
iText.IO.Source.PdfTokenizer.ThrowError(String error, Object[] messageParams)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader.ReadObject(PdfIndirectReference reference, Boolean fixXref)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader.ReadObject(PdfIndirectReference reference, Boolean fixXref)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfIndirectReference.GetRefersTo(Boolean recursively)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader.ReadObject(PdfIndirectReference reference, Boolean fixXref)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfIndirectReference.GetRefersTo(Boolean recursively)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfIndirectReference.GetRefersTo(Boolean recursively)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDictionary.GetAsDictionary(PdfName key)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfPagesTree..ctor(PdfCatalog pdfCatalog)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfCatalog..ctor(PdfDictionary pdfObject)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.Open(PdfVersion newPdfVersion)
Invalid offset for object 85404 0 R.
```

I'm not seeing any problems opening the PDF file in Chrome's reader, and it's not my PDF file, so I'm not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions on how to suppress these errors? Unfortunately, this is happening during the `Open()` method, not just during text extraction, so I can't skip over the problem to another page.

Here's my code:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using(var r = new PdfReader(path)) {
    var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(r);
    var numPages = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
    for(var pn = 1; pn <= numPages; pn++) {
        var st = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
        var page = pdfDoc.GetPage(pn);
        sb.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, st));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, which version are you using? I was able to read your file without any problem in iText 7.1.7.

Comment: Embarrassingly enough, I think it was a corrupted download. Closing the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to have been a corrupted download. Since I haven't run across this sort of issue with hundreds of other web sites and the same code to download, it could be specific to that web server. So I guess the answer is "try again"!